# how to send AWS sns notification to specific user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have a requirement where I will fetch a list of users from an AWS account. Let's say I have 10 users in the account. All of the 10 users are subscribed to one SNS topic. Out of 10 users, 4 users need to get a notification to rotate their credentials via email.

how can I achieve that using SNS and python? I just need to know the SNS part where I need to filter like SNS will send a notification to only 4 users

Comment: Either setup appropriate [subscription filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) or create an SNS topic per each user for dedicated channels.

Comment: without further clarification what the users might have in common, etc. that is not something you can do with SNS alone.

Comment: How do you define "users"? Are you referring to IAM Users? An IAM User does not have an "email address" attribute, so it is not obvious where to send an email. Even if the IAM Users are subscribed to an Amazon SNS topic, there is no direct link between the IAM User and the Email Subscription on the topic. I would recommend adding a tag to each IAM User for storing their email address, then having a process that separately emails users (using that tag for their email address) without using Amazon SNS.

Comment: yep that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a lambda and subscribe it to your topic instead of subscribing individuals.  Then in the lambda, you can do the filtering with your own custom logic and then use SES to email only the users that you need to notify.  One consideration is that the domains or email addresses that you send email from must be verified in SES before they are usable.

So this answer uses SNS, Python, lambda, and SES.

See

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-subscribe-sns-topic-same-account/